# does memory configuration affect cpu usage?

Tags: memory, processor

I've got this configuration:
intel i3 8100 CPU
8 GB DDR4 2400MHZ in a single module
MSI 1050 TI 4GB Video card
MSI Tomahawk Z370 MOBO

I notice 100% cpu usage especially when gaming even on 2011 games (Homefront) for example.

Now my question is does having single channel memory configuration put's more load on the cpu, does adding another ram module reduces the cpu load? and why?

Comment: Potentially yes, even though that is indirect, but you also need to consider how good the memory is compared to the CPU's power. You need to look at the efficiency of of your RAM and model (ie. DDR4, DDR3, etc.)

Comment: It's ddr4 as I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, so in any case, for example, I wanted to get a Gigabyte 1060 installed, but I did not consider the capacity of my PC itself, and I was warned that this could seriously threaten my PC's stability. An expert also warned me that in the future, it also a better idea to divide your total RAM across the total available slots in my motherboard for better and more enhanced performance, ie. if I have 32GB, and MB has 4 slots, get 4 x 8GB RAM and so on

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you check task manager/process (sort by cpu) and see what is causing the 100% cpu utilization. Adding more memory helps if the computer is constantly hitting hard drive cache which is an order of a magnitude slower, which you can check under task manager/performance.
But its not gonna help if its just a case of some services going bad or to many other programs loaded that need lots of cpu.

Comment: I'll do and get back to be this.

Comment: The game is using almost 90%, any way this is not my point, I saw reviews on this same configuration i3 8100 with nVidia 1050tiand the CPU usage in the same game same settings was about 60% -70% .

Comment: The only diff from the reviews is RAM single channel 8 GB instead of dual channel 16GB, so could it be that the increased CPU usage is caused by the memory configuration?